# Why my tcp client skip over the proxy and connect to server directly

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, proxy, localhost

I write a reverse proxy accroding to this https://gist.github.com/voorloopnul/415cb75a3e4f766dc590#file-proxy-py.

I need this to overwrite the authentication infomation from client side. Like following.

```
Client(passA)  --->   Proxy(overwrite passA into passB)  ---> Server(passB)
```

Where passB is the correct password and passA is random number.

The algorithms is SCRAMSHA256, a little bit complex but I manage to do this.
Eventhing works well when the proxy and the server is not on the same machine.
I have tried to deploy the proxy on **both windows and linux**. The proxy uses '***ip address***' to point to Server

While, when the proxy using '***localhost***' to point the Server, it is broken, that the authentication cannot be passed with one certain client(for which I made the proxy). But with the other clients, it also works well.

Shouldn't this be encapsulation and transparent to user?

Why the localhost so special and how can I fix this?

---

### Update the latest research

The authenication failed because the client connect to the server directly, so the password is not modified by my proxy.

```
Condition 1: Proxy on another machine. The proxy works.
Client(192.168.1.1) ==> Proxy(192.168.1.3:8000) ==> Server(192.168.1.2:6000)
```

-

```
Condition 2: Proxy on the same machine as the Server.
The proxy listen 0.0.0.0:8000 and forward packets to localhost:6000.

Client(192.168.1.1) ==> Proxy(192.168.1.2:8000) ==> Server(192.168.1.2:6000)

After the first connection, the rest connection becomes

Client(192.168.1.1) =====> Server(192.168.1.2:6000) without proxy.
```

That makes the proxy not work anymore.
Why the client will skip it in condition 2?

Comment: What do you mean by "all broken"? Is the reverse proxy trying to connect to itself by any chance?

Comment: The proxy connects to another port, so no chance it will connect to itself. According to the packets, the authentication routine is finished, but failed.

Comment: So the problem is in the application level, not the network level, right? You mention packets, do you mean you've already tried looking into packet captures with wireshark? And you didn't see any difference between what works and what doesn't?

Comment: Yes, I used tcpdump and wireshark to look into packets, all the same when it works or not.  **It must be the network that cause the problem.** I've tested the application under different condition as I mentioned.

Comment: "Why the client will skip it in condition 2" Does the server response include something that tells the client where it should connect to?

Comment: @Joni I found it, which fixed the bug, thank you.  But it is strange that the client will change the port only if the host is matched.